# How to use jarsigner for signing an apk?

Tags: java, android, signing, jarsigner, jar-signing

I have very little programming knowledge.I am able to open jar signer through the command prompt then I get various jar signer options,which i do not know how to use them.Can anyone explain me what should i type in the command prompt in order to sign the app?

Answer (score 43):

You can find all the information you need about this topic on d.android.com: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore
my_application.apk alias_name
```

One thing that cost me a few hours already, but is also mentioned in the official documentation:

> As of JDK 7, the default signing algorithim has changed, requiring you to specify the signature and digest algorithims (-sigalg and -digestalg) when you sign an APK

Comment: where should i put my keystore and apk files?

Comment: i have tried the following c\programfiles\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\jarsigner-verbose-sigalg SHA1withRSA-digestalg SHA1-keystore<xxxxx.keystore> myapp.apk

Comment: i am getting the error "system cannot find the path specified"

Comment: Probably because the command you posted is missing tons of spaces and other useful symbols. Try something like: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore <xxxxx.keystore> myapp.apk <alias_name>

Comment: what should i type in the <alias_name>?

Comment: should i put the keystore and apk files in the java folder?

Comment: i typed exactly what u said and i am getting the error "it is not recognized as internal or extenal command"

Comment: after trying dozens of times i get the error "ACCESS IS DENIED"

Comment: Please read through the whole guide: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp

Alternatively, you can simply sign your app using Eclipse.

Answer (score 15):

Use the jarsigner as below:

```
jarsigner -keystore <keystore_file> -storepass <storepassword> <filenameTosigned> <alias>
```

Comment: rahul bhai....i have tried the following    c\programfiles\java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\jarsigner-verbose-sigalg SHA1withRSA-digestalg SHA1-keystore<xxxxx.keystore> myapp.apk

Comment: where should i put the keystore and apk files

Comment: Tried this. But getting a warning also, Warning:
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a times
tamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's
expiration date (2042-07-31) or after any future revocation date.

Comment: You can ignore that warning.

Answer (score 4):

For -tsa option enter the next one:

```
jarsigner -verbose **-tsa http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161** -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore your_keystor_name.keystore YourAPK.apk youralias_key
```