# How to generate signed apk using ANT?

Tags: java, xml, ant

[THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512088/how-to-generate-apk-file-programmatically-through-java-code)

I have used this above link to generate an apk file using ANT.

But when i give "ant release" command in command prompt. I got an output as **"build successfully"**.

Can you please give me a solution for this.  I wanted to generate apk file when i run the program.

I have used Java JDK and Android SDK, Ant.

But i code must be in xml and Java JDK not in Android SDK.

Comment: Ant can not sign an APK file on it's own. Therefore you have to execute the external program `jarsigner` from within Ant. See [How to use jarsigner for signing an apk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457538/how-to-use-jarsigner-for-signing-an-apk)

Comment: In the above question i have mentioned **"THIS LINK"**, there you could have seen that **android update project"** command. may i know where should i declare that command and why that command is used.

Comment: I am sorry but you should rewrite your question, it is way too confusing and unclear what you are really asking.

Comment: I need to generate or build apk file through some java program where i select the Java SE source project and may be i have a button on the Java swings and when clicked it generate .apk file. I was confused that how to write a code to generate a Android project and apk file.