# Using adb, I get an error while trying to install an apk to my Android device

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, adb

Following is the command and error:

```
[raj@raj-arch apk]$ adb install android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk 
[100%] /data/local/tmp/android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk   pkg:
/data/local/tmp/android-armv7-release-unsigned.apk Failure
[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION] rm failed for -f, No such
file or directory
```

I'm using Ionic and Cordova. Really not sure what's going on with that error though.

Answer (score 0):

try `ionic run android` or `ionic emulate android` if on emulator.

Don't mix those.

Comment: What do you mean by mix?

Comment: adb with ionic, its better to run it from ionic.

Answer (score 0):

you can't install `unsigned` APKs.
Even if it's signed with the debug key, Android only allows a signed APK to be installed.

So you can either follow some of those https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#signing-manually or  [How to use jarsigner for signing an apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21457538/how-to-use-jarsigner-for-signing-an-apk)

or use the debug version:

```
adb install android-armv7-debug.apk
```